# Edit Photo from URL with Photo Editor SDK

Tags: javascript, photoeditorsdk

I'm using the [PhotoEditorSDK](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/) in my application,
but I'm getting the attached error.
in the annex also follows the code that I used to arrive at these results.

It seems to be cross-origin problem

but the SDK has a specific part to it.
I opened called with the support of the company, but so far nothing.
If someone has already experienced this problem, know the reason, or how to solve.
Please help me ;-;

```js
"use stricts";
/*link = http://localhost:8080/editar?&page=1&url=https://photos.google.com/lr/photo/AGj1epXDcMoRlOQ7QcWY9dZ2ALBIqhfJuTSz-ywrilsUhstrZ7wo26XkgDSBk4Jx2nJuIPm3LCFoKuo
*/
var editor;
var vars = getUrlVars();
var page = vars.page;
var url = vars.url;
window.onload = function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('editor');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI({
        container: container,
        enableUpload: false,
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        editor: {
            image: img,
            responsive: true,
            enableZoom: false,
            controlsOrder: ['transform', 'filter', 'adjustments', 'focus'],
            export: {
                download: false,
                format: 'image/jpeg',
                type: PhotoEditorSDK.RenderType.BLOB
            },
        },
        //your license below
        license: 'license',
        assets: {
            baseUrl: '/assets'
        },
    });
}

function getUrlVars() {
    console.log(window.location.href);
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf("#") + 1).split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split("=");
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- React Dependencies for the SDK UI -->
<script src="js/vendor/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!-- PhotoEditor SDK-->
<script src="js/PhotoEditorSDK.min.js"></script>
<!-- PhotoEditor SDK UI -->
<script src="js/PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="editor" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding-top: 65px;"></div>

<script src="js/editar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: how do you get bellow two file
<script src="js/PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI.min.css" />

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the image to load before pushing it to PhotoEditorSDK.

You should move your `editor =` block of code into the `img.onload=""` method.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

In the console, there's error message saying that the resource could not be loaded because of same-origin policy.

What you have to do is to enable CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) for loaded resource. You can see more information [here](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/html5/v4/resources/faq).

However, you may not have controll over loaded resources (e.g. allowing users to add image by specifying external URL).

In this case, you should think about implement a PHP "proxy" that will download image on your server (n.b. same-origin policy is for browsers) and then serve that image to the front-end. You have two options:

- Store the image on your server's filesystem and proceed the URL.
- Directly serve the content of image to the client, e.g. you could encode the image in `base64` and retrieve it via `XHR` request.